# need to relogin when testing using nightwatch.js and saucelabs IE driver

Tags: nightwatch.js, saucelabs

I’m trying to use sauce labs with nightwatch.js. I notice that when I use sauce labs IE driver Windows 8.1, when it navigates from one page of the site to another, it requires re-login even though I logged in initially (it redirects me to my site's login page). It seems that cookies are not being persisted correctly.

Here are my nightwatch.json settings

What should I do to prevent this? Seems like cookies are being cleared midway.

```
"saucelabsIE11Win8.1": {
    "selenium_host": "ondemand.saucelabs.com",
    "selenium_port": 80,
    "username": "test",
    "access_key": "example",
    "use_ssl": false,
    "silent": true,
    "output": true,
    "screenshots": {
        "enabled": true,
        "on_failure": true,
        "on_error": true,
        "path": "./screenshots"
    },
    "desiredCapabilities": {
        "acceptsSslCerts": true,
        "browserName": "internet explorer",
        "platform": "windows 8.1",
        "version": "11.0",
        "screenResolution": "1280x1024"
    },
    "selenium": {
        "start_process": false
    }
},
```

Comment: You may want to regenerate your Sauce Labs access key. Start by clicking on your name in the bottom left hand corner of the dashboard.

Comment: how does that have anything to do with cookies?

Comment: It doesn't. You have posted your Sauce Labs credentials publicly. If you are not concerned about someone abusing your account, please disregard.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many causes for the issue you are having. Here are a few possible solutions I have used in previous projects when cookies didn't work.

1. If you are using Sauce Connect there is an -a flag that handles basic authentication. From the Sauce Labs Docs:

   "Performs basic authentication when a URL on host:port asks for a username and password. This option can be used multiple times."

   More info: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48365781
2. You can use a pre-run executable such as an AUTOIT script. Here is an example addition to the desired capabilities that would enable the script to be run.

   {"prerun": { "executable": "http://url.to/your/executable.exe", "args": [ "--silent", "-a", "-q" ], "background": true, "timeout": 120 }}

   More info: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Test+Configuration+Options#TestConfigurationOptions-Pre-runExecutables
3. Pass in credentials with the URL. This is more of a last resort option, but does work in a pinch. Add the username and password into the url as follows:

   "http://Username:Password@yourwebsite.com"